# Explanation to the what() call

Tags: c++, syntax

```
using namespace std;

struct MyException : public exception
{
  const char * what () const throw () // <--- This
  {
    return "C++ Exception";
  }
};
```

Please consider the marked line.
Can somebody explain me the syntax used in that statement

I think i should have narrowed down my query to  **"const throw()"**   part only...

Thanks all for the replies

Comment: Your title is very vague and poor. Please change it to describe the specific syntax you're asking about so that the title describes the question. You should also demonstrate that you have performed some basic research. Which book are you using?

Comment: Do you think i should delete this question?

Comment: @Tri_Core you should _edit_ the question so that it is clear what you are asking. You have added text saying "I think I should have narrowed down my query to const throw() part only" - don't add that text, just _do it_, i.e. narrow down your query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a member function definition.

- `const char *` is the return type, a pointer to a constant character, by convention the first character of a zero-terminated string array.
- `what` is the function name
- `()` is an empty parameter list, indicating that the function takes no arguments
- `const` qualifies the function, so it can be called on a `const` object, and can't directly modify the object's members
- `throw ()` is an exception specification which prevents it from throwing any exceptions.

This overrides the virtual function declared in the `exception` base class, allowing you to get a text message describing the specific exception that was thrown:

```
try {
    // Throw a specific type
    throw MyException();
} catch (std::exception const & ex) {
    // Catch a generic type and extract the message
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';  // prints "C++ Exception"
}
```

Comment: I must point that it does not actually prevent exceptions from being thrown. `throw()` variant (now deprecated) tells that no exceptions are expected to be thrown so compiler can simplify code omit exception handling parts. However if exception is thrown it may lead program into inconsistent state since no proper cleanup is performed.

Answer (score 1):

`what` is a function that returns a `const char *`. It is also a function that *never throws an exception*.

Answer (score 1):

The line is a member function declaration for the class `MyException`. It follows the exact same syntax as any other function declaration.

`const char *` - is the return type of the function.

`what` - is the name of the function.

`()` - the (empty) parameter list. The method takes no parameters.

`const` - declares this to be a const function (in general, this means it should not change the state of the object).

`throw ()` - declares that the function throws no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

struct MyException : public exception
{
  const char * what () const throw () // <--- This
  {
    return "C++ Exception";
  }
};
```

It isn't clear from your question which bit in particular you are unsure of, but I would guess it is the `throw()`, as this is not commonly used.

This is used to document the types of exceptions the method can throw, which enables the compiler to check that:

1. When you use the method ,You are catching everything thrown
2. Are not throwing something that you should not be

The rest of the line is fairly standard:

`const char * what () const throw ()`

`what()` : A function named what.

`what() const`: what() is a const function, so it can be used on const objects of type `MyException`

`const char* what() const`: what is a const function, which returns a pointer to `const char`