# Can't understand the syntax/structure of this C++ expression

Tags: c++, try-catch, throw

Please let me clarify that I might use incorrect terminology while explaining the problem. Kindly bear with me - do point out the flaws, but I hope that the essence of my problem is conveyed between the lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

struct MyException : public exception { 
   const char * what () const throw () {
      return "C++ Exception";
   }
};

int main() {
   try {
      throw MyException();
   } catch(MyException& e) {
      std::cout << "MyException caught" << std::endl;
      std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
   } catch(std::exception& e) {
      //Other errors
   }
}
```

I'm trying to learn C++ , having previously learned C.

In the above code, I do not understand the syntax of the particular line:

```
const char * what () const throw ()
```

What I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323256/need-help-in-understanding-this-c-syntax-const-char-what-const-throw) is that

1. `const char *` is the return type, a pointer to a constant character, by convention the first character of a zero-terminated string array.
2. `what` is the function name
3. `()` is an empty parameter list, indicating that the function takes no arguments
4. `const` qualifies the function, so it can be called on a `const` object, and can't directly modify the object's members
5. `throw ()` is an exception specification which prevents it from throwing any exceptions.

But what I don't understand is :

While referring to functions in C, we define them as

```
return_type function_ name
  {function_body;
  }
```

And so while I understand `const char *` is the return-type here; and therefore `what` must be function_name; I don't understand what part is the function body.

I am newly aware of the `throw` function in C++; but why is there a `'()'` after `what`? And if `throw()` is a function then what is it's return type? Are we defining `throw()` here or `what()` here?

Comment: I admit that such syntax is rather poor and confusing, but you've posted rather complete explanation of this construct, why are you starting to assume that `throw()` is a function of some kind? `throw()` is a [dynamic exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) just like description says. Also I must point that it does not actually prevent exceptions from being thrown.

Comment: I could not understand points 4 and 5 of the explanation - I had a different version of the syntax of functions (as follows):

`return_type function_name (function_parameters)
{function_body;
}`

And when this did not match the format that was present in the question, I got all messed up.

Comment: As I said, please excuse me for usage of incorrect terminology - it will take some time for me to not call functions as something else and something else as functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While referring to functions in C, we define them as
>
> ```
> return_type function_ name
>     {function_body;
>     }
> ```

The same applies in C++. Just that there can also be additional optional specifiers between `function_name` and `{function_body}`, too.

> And so while I understand `const char *` is the return-type here; and therefore `what` must be function_name;

Yes.

> I don't understand what part is the function body.

Exactly what you would expect it to be - the portion between the curly braces:

```
{ return "C++ Exception"; }
```

> I am newly aware of the `throw` function in C++;

It is not a function.

> but why is there a '()' after `what`?

The reason you already stated in your question: "an empty parameter list, indicating that the function takes no arguments".

> And if throw() is a function

It is not. It is qualifying `what()` as contractually not throwing any exceptions.  The parenthesis of a function's `throw` specifier states the actual exception types that the function may throw, or it may be empty if none are allowed.

> Are we defining `throw()` here or `what()` here?

`what()`

Comment: Alright, so it's just another way of specifying that the function _what()_ has no input parameters is marked with _throw()_ and hence you are telling the compiler that the function **WILL NOT** throw any exceptions.

Okay so why is _const_ present? (before the _throw()_ )

The reason why I kept referring to _throw()_ as a function is because it is written that 

`const qualifies the function`

And so I assumed they are talking about _throw()_

Comment: @vedantgala the `throw()` qualifies `what()` as not throwing any exceptions. The `const` is there because of the reason you stated in your question in #4. It is qualifying `what()` as being a const method. For instance, if the `const` were not present, and the `catch` caught `e` by `const` reference, you would not be allowed to call `e.what()`. Rule of thumb: `const` always applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing there then it applies to the thing on its right.

Comment: Superb, I'm perfectly satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

This is a deprecated dynamic no-throw specifier. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).
It is not an additional function call. It rather specifies how this very function behaves, in this case, whether it throws exceptions or not, which it doesn't in this particular case.